# How to dynamically check/uncheck html checkbox by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I know that several questions about this topic have been asked, but I was unable to find an answer for my case.

I have a checked `checkbox` as

```
<input type="checkbox" name="text" checked="checked" />
```

I need to send ajax request by checking/unchecking, but I do not know what can be the reliable (with browser compatibility) for an `if statement` such as

```
if (this.value == 'on')
{
this.value = 'off';
ajax call;
}
else
{
this.value ='on';
ajax call;
}
```

Note that the value is not important here, and we need to catch `checked/unchecked`, but how control the checked element by `JavaScript` when the html original element has `checked="checked"`?

If using `checked` instead of `value` as

```
if (this.checked == true)
{
this.checked = false;
ajax call;
}
else
{
this.checked =true;
ajax call;
}
```

The tick of `checkbox` will not be changed in the browser (always ticked).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following should work:

```
function myFunction(elem)
{
    if (elem.checked)
    {
        alert("Im Checked");
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Im not checked");
    }
}
```

**Markup**:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="text" checked="checked" onchange="myFunction(this);" />
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QMhn5/

**Update**:
To change the check from other element:

```
document.getElementById("chk").checked = true;
```

or

```
document.getElementById("chk").checked = false;
```

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/QMhn5/1/

Comment: How to check/uncheck?

Answer (score 1):

If you can use jquery, this should work:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="c1" />


$("#c1").change(function(){
    var checked = $(this).is(":checked");
    console.log(checked);
    //ajax call
})
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XUgTC/ , try clicking the checkbox and look in the console.

Comment: I don't think the OP wants jQuery.

Comment: :) no need to apologize, I do that all the time.

Comment: @HanletEscaño yes I am attached to pure JS.