# How to set radio button value as checked or unchecked situation

Tags: javascript, html

```
<input type="radio" name="imgsel"  value="" checked />
```

My requirement is :  This radio button by default checked then value of this button is 'present'. When this button is unchecked , then value this button is 'absent'.
how can i do this?

please, help me .
Thanks in advance .

Comment: @DrewReese help me bro

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11700252/how-to-change-a-radio-button-value

Comment: See this comment for the answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/19666627/15721671

Answer (score 1):

```js
function valChange(element)
{
   if (element.checked)
  {
     alert("present");
  } else
  {
    alert("absent");
  }
   }
```

```html
<input id="button" type="checkbox" name="imgsel" 
onchange="valChange(this)" value="" checked />
```

Comment: Check Out This :- 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15105447/how-can-i-toggle-radiobutton

Answer (score 0):

The following example replaces the value of the checkbox when clicked.
First the click event must be bound to the checkbox. The EventHandler checks whether the box has already been checked. If not, it checks it and sets the value in the checkbox. And if it has not been checked, the other way round.

```js
let i = document.querySelector('input');

i.addEventListener('click', (ev) => {
  let el = ev.target;
  
  if (el.getAttribute('checked') === null) {
    el.setAttribute('checked', true);
    el.value = "present"         
  } else {    
    el.removeAttribute('checked');
    el.value = "absent"    
  }
  let checkValue = document.querySelector('input').value
  alert(checkValue)
})
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="imgsel"  value="" checked />
```